# All $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I have a question related to count the number of all $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$. Since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$ is a splitting field of $(x^2-3)(x^2-5)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. There is a theorem guarantee that (such theorem require $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$ to be a splitting field of some polynomial):

1. There is an automorphism maps $\sqrt{3}$ to $\sqrt{3}$ and fix $\Bbb Q$.
2. There is an automorphism maps $\sqrt{3}$ to $-\sqrt{3}$ and fix $\Bbb Q$.
3. There is an automorphism maps $\sqrt{5}$ to $\sqrt{5}$ and fix $\Bbb Q$.
4. There is an automorphism maps $\sqrt{5}$ to $-\sqrt{5}$ and fix $\Bbb Q$.

So there are $2\times 2=4$ possible automorphisms, $|\textbf{Aut}_{\Bbb Q}\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})|=4$. But my question is, is there indeed an automorphism maps $\sqrt{3}$ to $\sqrt{3}$ and meanwhile maps $\sqrt{5}$ to $-\sqrt{5}$? I know the answer is yes, but is it definitely true? Or is it so just by trivial reason? Or should we need a theorem to state this result? PS: I found that Hungerford explicit construct such four automorphisms, to check these are all indeed exist.

Comment: Using that the elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$ are of the form $$a_0+a_1\sqrt{3}+a_2\sqrt{5}+a_3\sqrt{3}\sqrt{5},$$ you can easily construct such automorphism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your descriptions of the four automorphisms ar lacking. For 1. and 2. you describe what happens to $\sqrt 3$, but not what happens to $\sqrt5$, and vice versa for 3. and 4.

Given an arbitrary element $a+b\sqrt3+c\sqrt5+d\sqrt{15}$ in your field, where $a, b, c, d$ are rational, the four automorphisms are:
$$
a+b\sqrt3+c\sqrt5+d\sqrt{15}\mapsto a+b\sqrt3+c\sqrt5+d\sqrt{15}\\
a+b\sqrt3+c\sqrt5+d\sqrt{15}\mapsto a-b\sqrt3+c\sqrt5-d\sqrt{15}\\
a+b\sqrt3+c\sqrt5+d\sqrt{15}\mapsto a+b\sqrt3-c\sqrt5-d\sqrt{15}\\
a+b\sqrt3+c\sqrt5+d\sqrt{15}\mapsto a-b\sqrt3-c\sqrt5+d\sqrt{15}
$$

Or, in words:

1. One automorphism that maps $\sqrt3$ to $\sqrt3$ and $\sqrt5$ to $\sqrt5$
2. One automorphism that maps $\sqrt3$ to $-\sqrt3$ and $\sqrt 5$ to $\sqrt5$
3. One automorphism that maps $\sqrt3$ to $\sqrt3$ and $\sqrt 5$ to $-\sqrt5$
4. One automorphism that maps $\sqrt3$ to $-\sqrt3$ and $\sqrt5$ to $-\sqrt5$

with the implicit understanding that the image of all other elements are defined by the properties of homomorphisms (as well as by fixing $\Bbb Q$, although that's superfluous in this specific case).

You should, of course, check that these are indeed automorphisms by showing that they are bijective homomorphisms.

Comment: So **must** I check that, say $\phi:a+b\sqrt3+c\sqrt5+d\sqrt{15}\mapsto a-b\sqrt3+c\sqrt5-d\sqrt{15}$ is indeed an automorphism? (In other words, it is not automatically so by any theorem). But for the case $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ over $\Bbb Q$. Since there is a theorem guarantee so, I don't need to check there is an automorphism maps $\sqrt{2}$ to $-\sqrt{2}$ this time.

Comment: The theorem I mentioned is [this](https://imgur.com/a/LUN3Ys7)

Comment: @Eric Depends on what you mean by "automatically". Yes, Galois theory gives you that there is a unique automorphism which fixes $\Bbb Q$, sends $\sqrt3$ to $-\sqrt3$ and $\sqrt 5$ to $\sqrt5$. On the other hand, your $\phi$ is a function which sends $\sqrt 3$ to $-\sqrt3$ and $\sqrt5$ to $\sqrt5$. Connecting the two is not completely automatic, and should in principle be done. One way of doing that is showing that your $\phi$ is an automorphism. The same is actually true for $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$ and the (quite obvious) non-trivial automorphism there.

Comment: I see! Yes, I think you completely get what I ask. Actually I haven't studied Galois theorem, I encountered this exercise in the section in the Hungerford's textbook before the Galois theorem section. My teacher told me that this it "redundant" to check such $\phi$ must exists. (She means it is trivial, and I think she means it does not need Galois theory either.) But I can't find a trivial reason that such automorphism which involves determining the way two "basis" map is definitely, trivially exist.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have to check all the computations suggested by @Arthur 's answer.

The degree of the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$ is 4 (because $1,\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5}$ and $\sqrt{15}$ are linearly independent, for example). Also, the field being a splitting field of a separable polynomial(over Q any poly with simple roots is separable) implies that the extension is ***Galois***. So the group of automorphisms will be either $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ or $\mathbb{Z}_4$. But since $\sqrt{3}$ $\mapsto -\sqrt{3}$ (and leave Q fixed) and $\sqrt{5} \mapsto -\sqrt{5}$(and leave Q fixed again) are distinct automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ respectively, that can be extended to automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$ (any automorphism of a smaller field may be extended to an automorphism of the larger field) and generate subgroups of order two in our Galois group G, it follows that the group cannot be $\mathbb{Z}_4$ (since $\mathbb{Z}_4$ has only one subgroup of order 2).

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Arthur you are right, I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have an automorphism for every election of signs. But you are no counting your morphisms well. For example, the morphisms 1. and 3. could be the identity.